# Jquery Carousel problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel, carousel

I am trying to use jCarousel (http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)

I have set up most part of it. When i click next.. only one element is shown instead of two.

[image]

Link: http://bakasura.in/king/elements/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the static cicular.html are `<li>` -tags without an polaroid-div

`<!-- Polaroid ends --> 
    </li>
    <li> 
      <!-- Polaroid starts-->`

and here: 2x `<li>`

`<!-- Polaroid ends --> 
    </li>
    <li>
    <li> 
      <!-- Polaroid starts-->`